# Can install Enterprise app on all tested iPads except for one

Tags: ios, ipad, enterprise, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an enterprise app, that has been installed on about 40 iPads without problems, and suddenly a user comes along with an iPad where the app simply won't install.

I have tried:

- Restarting the iPad
- Deleting the profiles
- Checking restrictions

But so fare without luck

I dont have physical access to the iPad so I cant see any log.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tried reseting the iPad?

Comment: No. I have a feeling the user would be a bit upset about this approch. I have, however, tried the hard restart.

Comment: How do you install the app on the iPad? With iTunes, over the air? What is the error message?

Comment: Over the air, using a simple webpage with a link to the app. We have 5 different apps using the same strategy, where it, so fare, just works. The error message is a pretty generic one: "The app could not be downloaded". It the same message you get when there is a problem with the provisioning.

Comment: have you checked the CPU architecture of your device and in your build setting?

Comment: @walinaqvi: A really good suggestion. Unfortunately the Architecture is correct. The app is running on several iPad4s and this is just another iPad4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was related to the time on the device. The clock was set 1 hour off.

Answer (score 0):

Check the iPad system version is suitable for your xcode, Check if this device are in your support list, It is device are jailbreak?

Comment: The device is running a supported version of iOS and is not jail broken

Comment: It's there any other Bundle ID conflict or something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is somehow related to the the specific device's settings. It is only a problem on that unit